Why is VoiceOver saying "level 1" around child nodes in an h2 heading on Chrome/MacOS and what does that mean?
Given the following HTML markup:
<h2>This is an h2 heading with a <strong>strong</strong> tag in it</h2>

Using Chrome (123.0.6312.107 / Official Build / arm64) for MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1, VoiceOver is reading the text for me as:
"this is an aitch two heading with a level one strong level one tag in it level one".
If I change the h2 heading to an h3, it would read the same except it would say "level two" instead of "level one" (and so on for other headings, with VoiceOver saying one less than the heading level).
Why is VoiceOver saying "level one" around the child node? Is this a setting, a bug, or is it expected? Assuming this is expected behavior, what does it mean and what information is it trying to communicate?
Additional Information

It does this regardless of the child node: strong, em, span, a...
VoiceOver does not do this in Safari or FireFox. In Safari, VoiceOver reads the above heading as "heading level two... three items... this is an aitch two heading with a... strong... tag in it" (note the ellipses are indicating pauses).
My VoiceOver settings are, as far as I know, set to the defaults; I have not deliberately changed any settings. I could not find a setting in Chrome that might control this, and the only one in VoiceOver Utility I've found influences it is verbosity (see below).
"Verbosity" is set to "High" for me, which as far as I know is the default. If I set this to "Low", VoiceOver stops saying "level N". Specifically, it is the "Status" item under the "Text" control which toggles this behavior.

In the event this behavior is not expected

I tried incognito as well as a guest profile, to rule out extensions influencing this behavior.
I first noticed this while browsing a site that had a strong tag inside of an h2. I found it to be odd, so I created an empty html page with just a heading for testing. While I initially made an html5 page with a doctype, charset, etc., I can simplify the markup right down to <html><body><h2>...</h2></body></html>, so it's safe to rule out specific markup.
Using Chrome on an older Mac (not running Sonoma), VoiceOver does not read "Level N".
Googling the issue, I found no information.
I asked ChatGPT4, which provided no useful information, except to say that the behavior "is not typical or expected under normal circumstances." Otherwise it suggested a few reasonable things to check.

Accessibility Tree
Here is a screencap of the accessibility tree, if that helps.


Could you share what Chrome exposes in the accessibility tree?

@Andy I added a screencap to the question, is that what you're asking for?

You might ask yourself why you're using the strong element in the first place, which has a specific semantic meaning that seems redundant in a heading. If all you're after is visual emphasis, use b. The answer, though, could be that the strong element elevates the hierarchical level of the text to one above that of the heading. I'm not sure.

@isherwood I didn't write the markup, I encountered it "in the wild", found what VoiceOver did to be odd, and that hurled me down this rabbit hole. As noted above, it's not just strong tags, it's any markup (including span, which has no semantic meaning and a tags, which are validly used in headings all the time).

Well is the behaviour the same for span or a tags? What isherwood suggests makes sense, and it might have been implemented partially. The HTML Standard mentions levels of importance of several strong elements, maybe something has been implemented here which results in the level to be announced and based on the heading level. ARIA does not define any levels on the strong role.

Yes, the behavior is the same regardless of what tag is used within an h2-h6 heading. My apologies if I'm being unclear. If I put a span tag (for example) inside of an h2 heading, it reads, "level one" around the contents in the span tag, and then again at the end of the heading contents.
